# React Transition Animation is not working as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have a problem with reactJS when trying to animate a signup form. The animation is supposed to fade the form in from the top when it appears and then when the user clicks signup it should fade out. Here is the code

```
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';
...
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    mounted: false
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mounted: false };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  getInitialState() {
    return { mounted: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: true });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    this.setState({ mounted: false });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    var child;
    if(this.state.mounted) {
        child = (<Modal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />);
    } else {
      child = (<div />);
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
            in={this.state.mounted}
            className="example"
            timeout={{ enter: 500, exit: 300}}
          >
          {child}
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the CSS App.css:

```
.example-enter {
  margin-top: 30px;
  opacity: .01;
}
.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease, margin .5s ease;
}

.example-exit {
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.example-exit.example-exit-active {
  margin-top: -30px;
  opacity: .01;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, margin .5s ease;
}
```

Can anybody point out where the problem is. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount in "react-transition-group" doc that CSSTransition element has property named "classNames", maybe u'll get a chance

Comment: this doesn't seem to address the question directly.

Comment: in his question, he used className so i think it caused the problem

Comment: In fact it is just  a typo. I wrote "className" while it should be "classNames"